# Various Categories of Subscribers in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

Can anyone explain My Lists, My groups, Publication Lists, Suppression Lists in Subscribers of Marketing Cloud?

Answer (score 1):

There are two data models in Salesforce Marketing Cloud: **Lists** and **Data Extensions**.

**What Is a List?**

A list is a compilation of subscribers that receive your communications. You create as many lists as you want to segment your subscribers so that you can target your email communications.

Use the list model when:

- your lists contain 500,000 subscribers or less long term
- you prefer simplicity over performance
- you do not require fast import speed
- you plan to use a limited number of subscriber attributes

A **[Group](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_groups_subcriber_feat_enhanced.htm&type=5)** belongs to the List data model and it's a subset of subscribers. There are two types of groups: Filtered Groups and Random Groups.

**Filtered groups** are segments of lists. You create a filtered group by filtering on profile attributes, preference attributes, filters, and measures. To refresh the group, you can use a group refresh activity or refresh the group manually. Subscribers who opt-out of sends from a group are retained in refreshed group as unsubscribed even if they no longer match the rules for the group.

**Random groups** are segments of lists or filtered groups or other random groups. You create a random group by splitting a subscriber list or filtered group. Only 12 random groups can be created from a list or filtered group.

**What Is a Data Extension?**

A data extension is a table within the application database that contains your data. You could use a data extension to store sendable subscriber data like lists or just to house relational data.

Use the data extension model when:

- your lists are going to be greater than 500,000 subscribers
- you support multiple subscriber data sets, with separate definitions
- you send global messages
- you require fast import speeds
- you implement triggered sends
- you use the SOAP or REST APIs
- you prefer a flexible subscription model

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_list_versus_data_extension.htm&type=5

---

**Publication Lists**

A publication list helps you manage how subscribers receive several different categories of emails or SMS messages. For example, send newsletters, advertisements, and alerts. Each of these is a different category, so create a separate publication list for each category. When you send a newsletter, associate the send with the newsletter publication list to identify to the system what kind of content is inside the publication.

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5

---

**Suppression Lists**

A suppression list is a list of subscribers that you don't want to receive your communications. Suppression lists filter out email addresses and prevent those addresses from receiving your messages. Suppression lists serve as a "do not contact" list for your email sends.

Read more here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_suppression_lists.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1):

These are all specific types of lists where Publication and Suppression Lists are specific types which are also useful when using the newer and more performant data extensions rather than the older lists.

- **Publication List / Suppression List**: Used to manage subscriber's opt-ins to specific communication types for example. This are non-sendable lists of subscribers with their status. You can select a publication/suppression list for a send (in addition to your audience), which means that everyone in your selected audience will receive the email unless they are unsubscribed from the publication list or on the suppression list. Publication Lists are the way to go when sending Email/SMS messages to sendable data extensions. Suppression lists are used with guided sends, user-initiated, and triggered email sends.

  > Use **publication and suppression lists** to manage opt-ins for your email account in Email Studio. Use either publication lists or suppression lists to control how subscribers receive your sends. Choose a publication list when sending email messages and SMS messages to a sendable data extension.
  > (Source: [Publication Lists in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5))
- **Groups**: Groups are a filtered subset of subscribers from a subscriber list. So they are the list-counterpart of filtered data extensions.

  > **A group** is a subset of subscribers. There are two types of groups:
  >
  > - Filtered Group
  > - Random Group
  >
  > Filtered groups are segments of lists. You create a filtered group by filtering on profile attributes, preference attributes, filters, and measures. To refresh the group, you can use a group refresh activity or refresh the group manually. Subscribers who opt-out of sends from a group are retained in refreshed group as unsubscribed even if they no longer match the rules for the group.
  >   Random groups are segments of lists or filtered groups or other random groups. You create a random group by splitting a subscriber list or filtered group. Only 12 random groups can be created from a list or filtered group.
  >   Use a group to create a targeted list of subscribers. For example, if you want to send an email to all the males in a list, you can create a group of just the males.
  > (Source: [Groups with Enhanced Subscriber Features in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_groups_subcriber_feat_enhanced.htm&type=5))

**Related documentation:**

- [List Versus Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_list_versus_data_extension.htm&type=5)
- [Groups with Enhanced Subscriber Features in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_groups_subcriber_feat_enhanced.htm&type=5)
- [Suppression Lists in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_suppression_lists.htm&type=5)
- [Publication Lists in Marketing Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_publication_lists.htm&type=5)